# Will rstan fit models faster with data stored as matrix or data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, logistic-regression, rstan

I am fitting a series of **multilevel logistic regressions** using `rstan` via the `map2stan` function in the `rethinking` library. Everything works fine, and the models all fit correctly and converge. However, the datasets I am working with are very large, so runtimes to fit each model are quite long (on the order of days). Consequently, I'm looking for any potential speedups I can find.

Right now, my data is stored in `data.frames` that all have similar structure with scaled continuous variables and categorical variables split up into 0/1 dummies. For example:

```
> str(dcc.s.dummy)
'data.frame':   85604 obs. of  34 variables:
 $ COST_DIST_ECOTONE        : num  -0.594 -0.593 -0.596 -0.591 -0.591 ...
 $ COST_DIST_HEA            : num  -0.663 -0.66 -0.672 -0.652 -0.65 ...
 $ COST_DIST_HISTOSOLS      : num  -2.09 -2.09 -2.09 -2.09 -2.09 ...
 $ COST_DIST_MEDSTR         : num  -0.178 -0.176 -0.177 -0.176 -0.174 ...
 $ COST_DIST_RIV_COAST      : num  0.34 0.337 0.335 0.341 0.338 ...
 $ DEM30_ASP_RE_2           : num  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DEM30_ASP_RE_3           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DEM30_ASP_RE_4           : num  1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ DEM30_ASP_RE_5           : num  0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DEM30_M                  : num  2.19 2.19 2.2 2.18 2.19 ...
 $ DEM30_SLOPE              : num  -0.797 -0.782 -0.839 -0.817 -0.76 ...
 $ DRIFT_THICK_1            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DRIFT_THICK_2            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ DRIFT_THICK_3            : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ DRIFT_THICK_4            : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ LOC_REL_RE               : num  -0.862 -0.857 -0.857 -0.845 -0.84 ...
 $ LOC_SD_SLOPE             : num  -1.08 -1.08 -1.08 -1.06 -1.06 ...
 $ SITE_NONSITE             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_DRAINAGE_RE_2: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_DRAINAGE_RE_3: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_DRAINAGE_RE_4: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_DRAINAGE_RE_5: num  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_DRAINAGE_RE_6: num  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_DRAINAGE_RE_7: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_EROSION_RE_2 : num  1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_EROSION_RE_3 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_EROSION_RE_4 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_EROSION_RE_5 : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_LOC_DIV      : num  -0.184 -0.22 -0.168 -0.316 -0.322 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_NATIVEVEG_2  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_NATIVEVEG_3  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_ESRI_NATIVEVEG_4  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ SSURGO_PH                : num  0.86 0.632 0.518 0.86 0.518 ...
 $ WATERSHED_INDEX          : int  3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
```

**Would converting the `data.frame` to a `matrix` using `data.matrix(frame, rownames.force = NA)` or similar reduce the amount of time it takes `rstan` / `map2stan` to complete sampling and fit the model?**

I've run across the argument in a number of places that operations performed on matrices are generally faster than those on data.frames. `Rstan` does all of it's heavy lifting in c++ though, so for all I know it's already doing a similar conversion anyway as part of its operations. Any insight or recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I recommend you try it both ways and time it to see which is faster. Start with a smaller dataset so the comparisons don't take as long at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the runtime is on the order of days and the compile time is about a minute, you are not going to notice the time it takes to first do anything on the R side, including whether the data were stored as a matrix or data.frame.

In other words, in this situation you should worry much, much more about whether the Stan code generated my `rethinking::map2stan` is inefficient rather than whether the data processing code in **rethinking** is inefficient. Since **rethinking** is not optimized for your use case, it is quite likely that **rstanarm**, **brms**, or hand-written Stan code --- especially utilizing linear algebra rather than the more scalar algebra code generated by `rethinking::map2stan`  --- will run a lot faster.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. That make a lot of sense. I'll take a much harder look at optimizing my Stan code.